# AS3 Saving list as .txt file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to save a list to a .txt file in AS3.
I was previously saving it as .ulist with:

```
var filefilter1:FileReference = new FileReference();
var names:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
names.writeInt(31);
names.writeObject(grabberMenu.grabbedAccounts.dataProvider.toArray());
filefilter1.save(names, "New User List.ulist");
```

So I put the list into an array.
Which worked fine, but I need to have it as a .txt file. I tried just changing the format to .txt like:

```
filefilter1.save(names, "New User List.txt");
```

which also worked, but when I opened the text file, each label from the list was there, but there were also unwanted random characters spread around. All I need each label from the list separated by a break (enter).

How can I save it to a .txt file without there being extra unwanted characters appearing? 
I'm still not advanced at AS3, so any advice would be very appreciated. I couldn't find any other people with situations like mine online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save as .txt, you should use writeUTFBytes instead of writeObject.

for example

```
names.writeUTFBytes("31\n");
var arr:Array = grabberMenu.grabbedAccounts.dataProvider.toArray();
for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    names.writeUTFBytes(arr[i].toString() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save any kind of object to an AMF file and use any extension you want. When loaded back, AMF files work exactly as native objects (vars, arrays, instances of classes, etc).

This is how you save the file (you can use any extension you want):

```
var file:File = new File("myFile.xxx");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open( file, FileMode.WRITE );
stream.writeObject(yourObject);
stream.close();
```

This is how you read it back:

```
var file:File = new File("myFile.xxx");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
var decodedObject;
stream.open( file, FileMode.READ );
decodedObject = stream.readObject();
stream.close();
```

If your object is not a standard object (`Array`,`Object`,etc) you have to register the class with [registerClassAlias](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias%28%29) so that Flash knows how to decode the AMF file into it's data type.